# How to add function argument as plot title with lapply?

Tags: r, variables, plot, title, lapply

I'm not showing you my real code because it's huge and ugly.
But I recreated the problem using standard r packages:

```
# a list of a few r standard datasets
datasets <- list(PlantGrowth, cars, faithful)

# a function that plots a dataset and adds its name to the title
plotstuff <- function(dataset) {
  plot_title <- substitute(paste("Plot of ", dataset, sep=" "))
  plot(dataset, main = plot_title)
}
```

The name of the dataset (i.e. function argument) is successfully added to the plot title when I run the function with individual datasets like

```
plotstuff(PlantGrowth)
plotstuff(cars)
plotstuff(faithful)
```

Since I have many datasets I would like to do this with lapply like this:

```
lapply(datasets, plotstuff)
```

But in doing so I get weird titles: Plot of [[(X,i) instead of the name of the dataset.
How do I make the name of the dataset appear in the plot titles using lapply?

Here's the only related topic I could find. (And it didn't really help...)

[Use variable name as plot title with lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575239/use-variable-name-as-plot-title-with-lapply)

EDIT:
Thanks!
But I don't seem to understand the other example.

"Use lapply on the names of the list items instead:"

```
lapply(names(afn), function(x) plot(afn[[x]], main=x))
```

First, I add names to the list:

```
datasets <- list(PlantGrowth = PlantGrowth, cars = cars, faithful = faithful)
```

And then I tried:

```
plotstuff <- function(dataset) {
  chart_title <- substitute(paste("Plot of ", dataset, sep=" "))
  plot(datasets[[dataset]], main = chart_title)
}
lapply(names(datasets), plotstuff)
```

Did not work... I also don't want to reference the list datasets inside the function. What if I want to use a second list with another name later?
Anybody know a solution for this example here?

Comment: Your list does not have names, so there's no way the `lapply` could know them. Try `names(datasets)`. For comparison, `L = list(a = 1, b = 2)`.

Comment: Name the list, then use the linked duplicate as guidance.

Comment: Thanks! Done that. I'm still stuck though (see edit)...

Answer (score 0):

Like the other question, `lapply` won't do what you want here. When it applies the function it applies it to the element of the list, not the items that were used to create the list.

How about:

```
datasets <- list(PlantGrowth = PlantGrowth, cars = cars, faithful = faithful)

plotstuff <- function(dataset, name) {
  plot_title <- paste("Plot of ", name, sep=" ")
  dev.new()
  plot(dataset, main = plot_title)
}

mapply(plotstuff, dataset = datasets, name = names(datasets))
```

Comment: Thanks! mapply looks promising!
When I an this code I got three popups, all three figures with the right titles!
But when I check Plots in the RStudio bottom-right corner I only find the first plot (Plot of PlantGrowth).
I tried to run the code again but it didn't work a second time.
I don't understand what dev.new() does. Any hint?

Comment: @mire-mike, `dev.new` opens a new plot window. If you didn't use `dev.new`, each plot would overwrite the previous plot in the same plot window. I think RStudio should open tabs for each `dev` but I haven't used RStudio recently.